# Best way to show tables on mobile and tablet common dimension

Tags: usability, tables, responsive-design, mobile-web

I have a *visual* problem that breaks *usability* in my opinion.

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap V.3 and I have a web form.

I must show a table with this information:

> City, Address, Latitude, Longitude, TextField, Tels

`Tels` can be more than a value (my JavaScript manages that) and the `TextField` commonly has a number of characters that is approximately 85 (can be more, can be less)...

It is visually acceptable to append rows one below another (in desktop view), but on smartphones or tablets is really bad.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no more *cowardly* attitude than one who votes negatively on a question and does not leave a constructive comment. It is a despot action.

Comment: compensated the downvote with an upvote :P
You can nest the rows and can make it collapsable-expandable on tapping the relevant icon.
If you are making a data driven design and contains charts and/or complex tables on the whole platform then you can launch the desktop view on the mobile. It will not provide the pleasant experience but will not provide bad UX for sure. Pinch in - pinch out will work fine but consider it as a last option.
@alessadro

Comment: Thanks, my design is not complex, is a simple form, the only `bad` is that have that table. Please, could you show me an example of what are you saying? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See this few examples below. Different approaches to table presentation in mobile context.

1. First on top represents swipeable columns in mobile view.
2. Second screen refers to few-columns-in-one-column approach :)
3. Third one in an example of collapsable / expandable menu which can
   be helpful in combination with example nr 2.

Inspired by Wikipedia, Atlassian Confluance and others.

[image: Atlassian Confluance - Swipeable columns]

[image: Nested columns]

[image: Wikipedia - Collapsable / Expandable]